# ios: simulate touch: errors when trying private framework

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to simulate touch in iOS. There some pointers in SO suggest that I could try GraphicsServices/GSEvent.h in the private framework. However, when I followed the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771948/add-graphicsservices-private-framework-into-ios), I got these errors:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
    "_GSCopyPurpleNamedPort", referenced from:
    -[TestGraphicsServicesAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in TestGraphicsServicesAppDelegate.o
    "_GSSendEvent", referenced from:
    -[TestGraphicsServicesAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in TestGraphicsServicesAppDelegate.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any suggestion? Thanks

edit:
the code I used is from [Using GraphicsServices.h/GSEvent as well as compiling CLI iPhone tools with Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017367/using-graphicsservices-h-gsevent-as-well-as-compiling-cli-iphone-tools-with-xcod).

Looks like the errors are from this line.

```
    mach_port_t thePortOfApp = GSCopyPurpleNamedPort...
    GSSendEvent(&record, thePortOfApp);
```

Comment: What's the code where you want to simulate a touch event?

Comment: I followed the suggestion on the answer of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017367/using-graphicsservices-h-gsevent-as-well-as-compiling-cli-iphone-tools-with-xcod

Comment: Have you added the GS framework to your app? Is that the only occasion you use a GS method? Maybe you simply use `sendActionsForControlEvents:` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I made some mistakes when I added the framework.
Somehow I got my project working now.

The errors have gone away after I did a couple things.
In **Build Setting**, I changed Always **Search User Paths** to **Yes**.
Added the path to the private header in **User Header Search Paths**.
Also, in **Build Phrases tab**, I add the GraphicsServices in the **Link Binary with Libraries** section.

Now I can do simple stuff like GSEventLockDevice() and simulating pressing home button.
Still have no clue about touch.