# Undefined symbols for _GSGetPurpleSystemEventPort / _GSCopyPurpleNamedPort

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I need to call these two private APIs to get the purple ports for the front most applications on iOS 6. I have the header files but when linking it always gave me this error:

**Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

```
    "_GSGetPurpleSystemEventPort", referenced from:  
      -[ViewController getFrontMostAppPort] in ViewController.o  
  "_GSCopyPurpleNamedPort", referenced from:  
      -[ViewController getFrontMostAppPort] in ViewController.o  
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

It seems I need to reference some missingframework or do some other tweaks to get around this? If so, which framework/step am I missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Jack.

Comment: These are private APIs that you really shouldn't be using. What are you trying to do, and why?

Comment: I understand these are private APIs. I need to simulate touch events from background on jailbroken devices and this would be a private app. According to SO link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701155/send-a-global-touch-event-on-ios-6 it seems these APIs are the right way to go.

Comment: Sure, if it's a private app on a jailbroken device, then fair enough -- just checking. :) What version of Xcode are you running? Are you targeting iOS 6 specifically? (If so, this is indeed the SDK you have installed, correct?)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply friend. Yeah, I'm targeting iOS 6 specifically (6.1.2 to be precise) for this app and using xCode 4.6.3 for its development. I just found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076440/ios-simulate-touch-errors-when-trying-private-framework on a similar issue but couldn't find the GraphicsFramework framework it mentioned. Any suggestions?